# what are the place local storage used in magento2

Tags: magento2, local-storage

What are the place local storage used in magento2,

please explain

1. how to use effectively
2. the configurations , classes involved in local storage

Comment: Please clarify what do you want to ask?

Comment: i just want to know the local storage usage in magento2

Answer (score 1):

classes involved in local storage:

```
VandoName/ModuleName/CustomerData/Sample.php
```

also check [vandor](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/CustomerData/CompareProducts.php):

```
[vendor/magento/module-catalog/CustomerData/CompareProducts.php]
```

If learn more follow:
https://aionhill.com/magento-2-module-development-guide-part-4-knockout-js